# 4 jobs and 3 people, which job is extra?

Tags: knowledge

A Housekeeper, a Doctor, a Baker and a Detective are gathered in one place. Only 3 of them are people (and none has more than 1 job).

Who is not and why?

Comment: Is it "an" Housepkeeper?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL I assume so, in analogy with "an hour"

Comment: Have you seen the movie "A housekeeper's revenge"?

Comment: Never heared of such

Comment: I guess English isn't your native language, is it?

Comment: "A Housekeeper" would be correct. In "hour", the "h" is silent, while the "h" is pronounced in "housekeeper." The usage of "a" vs "an" has more to do with the pronunciation of the word than the actual spelling. I edited the question to correct this mistake since it is clearly not a clue.

Comment: Given the accepted answer, Baker is not apropos to the "gathered" clue.

Comment: @ClaytonColwell "gathered" means "present", so I observe no problem in this.

Comment: Gathered doesen't mean present, it means having come together. And that clearly doesn't work. (But in my opinion, the whole puzzle doesn't work.)

Comment: @MOehm that is definetly not a logical deductive quiz (which is clearly defined in tags) where incorrect perception of a single word may be a big problem, instead it is a knowledge and experience based question which can be only answered by those who are familiar with the source and who can find similarity between situations in quiz and the source. Taking into account popularity of the source (which comes in many different variations for any taste), this question's answer is not a mystery behind 7 seals. The detective from this question would guess it easily.

Comment: Don't try to be smug about creating a bad puzzle. I am familiar with the setting, but the puzzle just doesn't work. rot13(Onxre Fgerrg vfa'g n onxre; vg'f n fgerrg. Onxre Fgerrg 221O vfa'g n onxre, rvgure; vg'f na nqqerff be n ubhfr. Lbhe svefg fragrapr qbrfa'g jbex, orpnhfr gur cynpr jurer gurl zrrg vf bar bs gur guvatf gung ner tngurerq. Guvax nobhg vg: Vg qbrfa'g znxr frafr. Ng nyy.)

Comment: rot13(Zrn Phycn'f nafjre svgf zhpu orggre, ohg vg'f abg n cresrpg svg, orpnhfr bar qbrfa'g zvk crefbaf naq vanavzngr guvatf va qrfpevcgvbaf yvxr guvf. "Orggl, Crgre naq n obk ner tngurerq va gur unyy" vf fgenatr. V'z svar jvgu chmmyrf gung nera'g jung gurl frrz, ohg cyrnfr chg fbzr rssbeg vagb vg. Abj vs lbh pbhyq svaq n jnl gb erjbeq lbhe fragrapr fb gung vg pbhyq zrna obgu "FU, QJ, ZU naq n onxre unir zrg" naq "FU, QJ, ZU zrrg va Onxre Fgerrg", gung jbhyq or pyrire. Ohg whfg guebjvat va n onxre naq gura fnlvat "Un, un, vg jnf Onxre Fgerrg, bs pbhefr, qba'g lbh xabj nalguvat?" vf whfg ynml.)

Comment: @MOehm The puzzle doesnt work despite being solved in under 1 hour (and not by you)? Looks like an envy.

Comment: Yes, you've read that correctly: Your puzzle doesn't work. I've explained why. It was solved, I'll give you that, buit it wasn't exactly well received. Meanwhile,you've put in more effort into defendig it than you've put into creating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Baker, because

> It's Sherlock Holmes, the detective, Dr. Watson, the doctor, and Mrs. Hudson, the housekeeper, who are all gathered in 221B Baker Street.

Comment: Right answer this is!

Comment: I like the answer, but this doesn't make the baker a 'job', which contradicts the '4 jobs' in the title.

Comment: It's not a *job*, but it is related to an *occupation*.

Answer (score 6):

The Doctor, because

> One of the people has a doctor degree, allowing them the title Doctor. This is not a job but a title.

Comment: No, here a doctor is actually a job, not a title.

Comment: @Arctomachine it was worth a try

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is

> the Baker

Because

> The Baker is not a "person" anymore, but a corpse. He was found dead in his home, the Doctor is here to pronounce the death while the Housekeeper answers the questions of the Detective.

Comment: No. Nobody have died there. You guessed who, but not why.

Answer (score 2):

Baker, as

> It can be a person, but *not* necessarily, as it can be an *oven* or similar lifeless object that bakes.

Comment: That is the closest guess so far, but not yet right.

Answer (score 1):

The Baker, because

> The Doctor's surname is Baker (e.g. [Tom Baker](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Baker) from Doctor Who)

Comment: This is only half right. You guessed who, but mistaken why.